# POST JSON data to API script not parsing data

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to post json data using cURL to
an API script that submits the data to an
application.  I use file_get_contents('php://input')
and the data does not get submitted to the application
But if I type in an actual email address in the "contact_email" 
in the API it submits the email to the application.
Here is the cURL script first:

`

```
$data = '
 {

 "customer":
     {
      "first_name":"John",
       "last_name":"Smith",
       "email":"frednow9901@aol.com",
       "phone_number":"2125555555",
       "billing_address":"212 Any Street",
       "billing_city":"Any City",
       "billing_state":"New York",
       "billing_zip":"10012",
       "billing_country":"USA"
      }


}

';                                                                                                                                                     

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/acadd.php');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

`

**and here is the API script it posts to:**

```
 <?php


$json_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$cart = json_decode( $json_data );

$email = $cart->customer->email . 

// Set up an object instance using our PHP API wrapper.
define("AC_URL", "https://account.api-us1.com");
define("AC_API_KEY", "api key");
require_once("./ac-api-php/includes/ac.class.php");
$ac = new AC(AC_URL, AC_API_KEY);

$post_data = array(
    "contact_email" => $email , // include this or contact_id
    "automation" => "9", // one or more
);
$response = $ac->api("automation/contact/add", $post_data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";?>
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` return in your API script?

Comment: You mean use print_r($_POST) instead of get_file_contents('php//input') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:
`$email = $cart->customer->email .`

You have a period after the retrieval of the email property. This attempts to concat that with the define statement which would return 1. So sample@email.com would actually be sample@email.com1.

Comment: I Removed the period and replaced it with a semi-colon ; and it worked thanks alot!